# BigQuery SQL same column multiple expressions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using Google's Big Query service to do some data processing...my database looks like:

```
value
-----

'a'
'b'
'a'
'a'
'a'
'b'
```

I want to write a query to count the occurrences of the various values.

Example:

```
Count('a')   Count('b')
----------   ----------
4             3
```

I'd normally use Case to solve this; but BQ doesn't support Case.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I would suggest is a `group by`:

```
select value, count(*)
from t
group by value
```

But you seem to want the values in one row.  According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-reference#otherfunctions), it does support `case`.  If you prefer, you can use `if`:

```
select sum(if(value = 'A', 1, 0)) as A, sum(if(value = 'B', 1, 0)) as B
from t
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I would only add the option to use LOWER to make sure you don't get different results for upper and lowercase, supposing the db accepts mixed cases.